# Got an index that I need to match with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a bar chart with for example this array:

```
[12, 32, 42, 32, 43, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

So I have this array from markers from a google map with a length of 6, so from index 0 to 5.

I have an highlight event on the bar chart that when fired, it gives me the pointindex. I use the pointindex to get the marker from the google maps array, like: "gmap.markers[pointindex]". This works fine for the first 5 values from the bar chart array. but the ninth value from the bar chart array has the pointindex 8, but my google maps array only has 0 till 5 as index. So it doesn't work anymore. Basicly the pointindex 8 is basicly the index 5 from the google maps marker array.

This problem would also occur with as example these values.

Bar chart array: `[12, 32, 42, 32, 43, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]`

Google map marker array with a length of 7, so index from 0 to 6.

I have this code for the highlight of a bar in the chart, this event is fired and I do stuff with the marker to highlight a marker(basically change the icon.

```
chart.bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        marker = gmap.markers[pointIndex];
        if (marker !== null && marker !== undefined) {
            marker.setIcon('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png');
        }
    }
);
```

As I explained when there is empty data in a pointindex of the bar chart array, the index of the bar doesn't match anymore with the index of the google marker.

I thought in my head to copy the bar chart array to a new array and remove all values that contain "0". and than compare the value from the bar chart array with the new array without "0" values's to see what the index is in the new array. So that it would match again with the google map marker index. But then you have the problem that if the bar chart array has 2 values that are the same, then this method doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know a solution to this, in my head the problem is really simple, but I can't figure it out in code.

Comment: Why do you have `&amp;&amp;`? Copy-paste error?

Comment: Because the Javascript is in a JSF page, this is needed for JSF to parse it properly, I will change it to && ;)

Comment: So how do the bars in the chart map to markers? What is your app doing? If there are no markers for the bars to map to, then how would it make sense to map it in this way?

Comment: So Nina's solution should work here because the array indexes with values are maintained and should map directly to the markers array.

Comment: The thing as you see in the eventListener I get a pointIndex, in the case with month 9, it's 8. and since there is no 8 as index in the marker array, the function in the listener does not work anymore. So pointindex needs to become 5, because it's 8 in the chart, but 5 in markers array.

If I do Nina's solution I get indeed the bar chart array without the 0-values, but how do I know in the code to what value I need to change the pointindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Alex for the idea, and thanks @NinaScholz for the help, but I think you misunderstood my question, I know it was a vague question, sorry.

I have solved it by doing this.

when the page is loaded I do this:

```
var barArray = PF('dataChart').plot.data[0];
var mappingArray = new Array(barArray.length);
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < barArray.length; i++) {
    if (barArray[i] !== 0) {
        mappingArray[i] = j;
        j++;
    } else {
        mappingArray[i] = null;
    }
}
```

And the listener now does this:

```
chart.bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        marker = gmap.markers[mappingArray[pointIndex]];
        if (marker !== null && marker !== undefined) {
            marker.setIcon('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png');
        }
    }
);
```

So basically I make a new array that is as long as the chart array, if the value from the chart array has a value that is not 0, I set the value of this index in the mappingArray to a counted up index, that matches with the google markers index. If this can be done better, please do tell!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with the preserved index and the right index for sparse access.

```js
var barChart = [12, 32, 42, 32, 43, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    filtered = [];

barChart.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a && filtered.push({ value: a, index: i });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This only removes the 0 values from the bar chart array, these are not false values. There is no measured data on those points.

Checkout this image: http://i.imgur.com/eWCrdYU.png 1 to 12 on the chart are months. only 6 months have measured data, so only those have a latitude and longitude. So there are only 6 markers.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Use: `document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(barChart, null, '    ') + '</pre>';`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, what would change that?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, ok, i see.

Comment: @NinaScholz Check my solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

So @Nina's solution works in principle but not in terms of UI interaction.

Basically you need to see if the bar that was clicked has a value, and if it does, which index it maps to in Nina's filtering solution. Once you have the index that the value lies in from the filtered array, you can map that to your markers array.

**To do this:**

I think your best bet is, when building the bar chart to maintain an array with an object that is like `{ filteredIndex: N }`. This array will be same length as the bar chart and tells you which index it maps to in the filtered array. If the data is 0, then the filteredIndex will be null.

You can do this simply by iterating your data and pushing the value to the filtered array if it's value is greater than 0, and maintaining the index, in a separate mapping array.

Comment: Indeed, I thought of this. But then the problem arise, that when you have the same value in the array, 2 10's for example. Then how do your correctly map it.

Comment: Also if there is no data in one point of the chart, there is no location.

Comment: With nina's solution I could filter out the 0 values. And then with the pointindex get the data out of the original chart array and then search with that value in the filtered array, and get the index out of the filtered array, this index would match with the markers. But the problem is that when there are 2 of the same values in the array this does not work anymore right?

Comment: @WesleyEgbertsen, please supply some more example data.

Comment: @NinaScholz If I have a chart array with [10,2,5,0,0,10,0,0] and a marker array with a index from 0 to 3, because there are 4 non 0 values in the chart array. Now you have the problem that when you search with the value of the orignal value in the filtered array that there are 2 10's. How would you know which one is correct in the code.

Comment: @WesleyEgbertsen, thank you, i understand. just a minute

Comment: @WesleyEgbertsen so now hoping you understand what I'm saying here. You need to iterate your data and maintain a new array that contains a rule for mapping from the bar chart data to the non-zero filtered data.

Comment: @Alex I see what you mean, so make another array same length as the bar chart array. Iterate the orignal array if the value of a index from the orignal has a value in the other array at the index set the index that matches the markers one right? If the the value of the orignal has none, then null?

Comment: @Alex I will try to code this and report back, thanks for the idea!

Comment: That's exactly right... It's just a new array to map between the two

Comment: @Alex Check my solution I posted.